# Ошибка при выгрузке информации из Html-таблицы [javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, table

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь пройтись циклом по html таблице и вытащить информацию из определенных столбиков, но появляется ошибка:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#table > tr:nth-child(i) > td.copy-name' is not a valid selector.
> at :5:30

Понимаю, что ругается на использование индекса (i) в nth-child, но как можно по другому это реализовать ?

```
var massive = [];

for(let i = 1; i < RowsCount; i++)
{
    var Item_Name = document.querySelector("#table > tr:nth-child(i) > td.copy-name").textContent;
    var Item_Href = document.querySelector("#table > tr:nth-child(i) > td:nth-child(3) > a").href;
    var Item_Cost = document.querySelector("#table > tr:nth-child(i) > td:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > span:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2)").textContent;

    massive.push([Item_Name, Item_Href, Item_Cost]);
}
```

Comment: что-то я заблудился...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы переменная заменялась на значение в строке, используйте [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var massive = [];

for(let i = 1; i < RowsCount; i++)
{
    var Item_Name = document.querySelector(`#table > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td.copy-name`).textContent;
    var Item_Href = document.querySelector(`#table > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(3) > a`).href;
    var Item_Cost = document.querySelector(`#table > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > span:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2)`).textContent;

    massive.push([Item_Name, Item_Href, Item_Cost]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!